# GA4-graph on parametter of events

Tags: report, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I use Gogle analytics 4 with tag manageur to track my website user
I creat a tag that can track click [image: clicked text data]
As you can see the text information is here

But I can't manage to build a table of that in the explorer report section. I alredy try to creat a costum dimension and it fail.
any help please ?

thank you very much